# Parse JSON from response with python requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to parse JSON data from a response:

If use my browswer to go to: `/url/gold/stuff/here`

I get a response in the browser as:

```
window.data_gold = [{'gold':' room 123' } , {'better gold':'room 1234'} , {"best gold": "in cellar"}];
```

How can I extract the JSON data out of the response

```
window.data_gold = json
```

My code:

```
import requests,json

url     = '/url/gold/stuff/here'
r       = requests.get(url,timeout = 30)
newJSON = r.text
```

The above returns all the text, .json does not work.

Comment: What you got is not json. It's javascript.

Comment: @Leonardo Thats just semantics, how do I parse this.

Comment: It's actually an important distinction @Leonardo.Z made; you have to convert the Javascript into valid JSON, which may or may not be a viable long-term option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
data = json.loads(r.text[19:-1])
```

**Edit:** it doesn't like that, but this works:

```
import ast

data = ast.literal_eval(r.text[19:-1])
```

which gives

```
[{'gold': ' room 123'},
 {'better gold': 'room 1234'},
 {'best gold': 'in cellar'}]
```

Comment: good to see you again. The '19' should be all characters up to the square backet?

Comment: Yup, and :-1 to trim the ";" off the end.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hideous looking one-liner that will pull the json out of that particular response and put it in a dict.

```
d = json.loads(r.text.split("=")[1].replace("'", '"')[:-1])
```

It's pulling the json itself out of the javascript statement, replacing the single-quotes with double-quotes (because the json module won't accept single-quotes), and then feeding it the json module.

**Edit** As pointed out by Hugh Bothwell, using `ast.literal_eval` instead of the json module avoids the single-quote issue, so you're left with

```
d = ast.literal_eval(r.text.split("=")[1].strip(" ;"))
```

The `.strip(" ;")` Will strip the ';' off the end and the whitespace from the beginning.

Comment: _(because the json module won't accept single-quotes)_

  That's because JSON won't accept single-quotes as [delimiters](http://www.json.org/string.gif) :)